# Can libuv(node.js's async lib) run on Apple IOS / Android?

Tags: android, c++, ios, c, libuv

I have done some research to this effect but it is unclear if this is possible to use libuv on IOS/Android? If its not possible what is restricting it?

I am looking to write a C++ library that I can use for the same application on IOS, Android, Windows, OSX and Linux. Libuv seems to come close to fitting all of the requirements for sockets and threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libuv` has a build target for [Android](https://github.com/libuv/libuv#android). There's none (officially) for iOS at the time of writing.

Comment: Here is a [script](https://gist.github.com/litesync/d7c484ccfd9552d88249ade4ebc69bba) for compiling libuv for iOS as fat libraries (multi-platform)

Answer (score 4):

Actually `libuv` hasn't a build target for iOS, but you always can add it's source files to your `xcode` project and build. I have build it this way and it works fine for me.